# How can I force R to display 2 decimal points in a large double?

Tags: r

I'm trying to sum a vector of doubles in a data frame.  When the sum is relatively low, this works as intended.

```
df <- data.frame(
  numbers = c(50, 632.5, 12.45)
)

sum(df$numbers)
# 694.95
```

But when the sum gets higher, the R begins to round the sum.

```
df <- data.frame(
  numbers = c(50000000, 632.5, 12.45)
)
sum(df$numbers)
# 50000645
```

How can I stop R from eliminating these decimal points?  The output I want is:

```
sum(df$numbers)
# 50000645.95
```

Comment: Note that you can encounter [floating point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059) issues. You might need [arbitrary precision](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/Rmpfr-pkg.pdf) numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the number of digits in options, you can set whatever works for you. For example:

```
options(digits = 10)
sum(df$numbers)
[1] 50000644.95
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you only want to change the settings for this computation, you could use:

```
    print(sum(df$numbers, digits = 10))
```